# how to deal with big memory footprint of plots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm doing some simulations that end up taking quite a bit of memory. The numbers themselves are ok for my machine though. But when I try to plot them, I run out of memory. I guess matlab's plots are a special format that makes use of all the data available. However, I'd like to skip that step, and just generate a .jpg or .png directly. I don't even need/want the plot to pop up on the screen, I'd rather just save it directly to file, and bring it up later when I want.

Is such a thing possible in matlab?

Comment: Try creating the figure as invisible: `figure('visible','off'); plot(...); print filename.png -dpng`

Comment: What are you plotting? Thousands of points?

Comment: @LuisMendo that was exactly what I was looking for, feel free to post it as an answer, and I will accept.

Comment: @Jonas I was trying to plot imagesc with ~300 000 data points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the figure as invisible:

```
figure('visible','off')
plot(x, y); %// Insert your plot commands here
print filename.png -dpng %// print figure to file
```